# How to retrieve specific namespace in XML files using Xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I do have an XML file that starts as following:

```
<wfs:WFS_Capabilities xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" ...>
```

I do have the full xml file in an xsl:variable named="CAPAPILITIES" and the namespace identifier "ogc" in an xsl:variable named "prefix". I tried the following but it does not work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$CAPABILITIES/namespace::*[name()='$prefix']" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> and the namespace identifier "ogc" in an xsl:variable named "prefix"

You need to remove the quotes around `$prefix`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$CAPABILITIES/namespace::*[name()=$prefix]" />
```

in order to compare the namespace node's `name()` against the *value* of the `prefix` variable instead of against the literal string "dollar-prefix".